# Android Menu Codes in separate Class file

Tags: android, oop, optionmenu

In my android application option menu should be available in every UI. So I need to separate those codes to a separate class file instead of repeating same code in every Activity. How can I do this in Android ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to inherit from a custom class that itself derives from 'Activity'. In this base class, you have the common code for the options menu.

Comment: I didn't get what you have said.
My class is Search and I have contain codes for option menu in a class called MyMenu. Do you ask me to extend Mymenu in Search class ?

Comment: You can have a BaseSearch class that uses MyMenu, and Search and siblings of Search can inherit from BaseSearch.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2010/12/01/android---sharing-an-options-menu-between-activities.aspx